# Fabric Js Bounding to rect, image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have tried to make skew positions by applying transform matrix

Almost my work is done but control is not set as per the rotation and skewed positions

Please guide me for the same.

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/eokrLt2h/2/'
```

Comment: You will have a better chance getting an answer if you include the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Please check the JS Fiddle for the same i already shared the code https://jsfiddle.net/eokrLt2h/2/